# How do we know that the expression in the law of total probability converges to a finite value?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, convergence-divergence, conditional-probability

Let $<A_{i}>$ be a countably infinite partition of sample space $\Omega$. Then the probability of an event $A$ is given by,

$$P(A) = \sum_{n = 1}^{\infty} P(A_{i})\cdot P(A|A_{i})$$

The derivation of the theorem uses the countable additivity axiom.

How are we so sure that the sum converges?

Answer (score 3):

We are sure exactly because of countable additivity. We can rewrite the result $$ P(A) = \sum_i P(A\cap A_i).$$ This follows immediately from countable additivity because the sets $A\cap A_i$ are disjoint and $\bigcup_i (A\cap A_i) = A.$ (And these two facts follow from the fact that $A_i$ is a partition of $\Omega$.)

I'm not sure why the convergence of the sum would be a separate consideration. In fact if we were working in an infinite measure where $P(A)=\infty,$ it would still be true and the sum wouldn't converge. But since we're in a probability space, $P(A)$ is finite.

Comment: How do we know that the axiom doesn't lead to a contradiction here? The axiom says the sum must be equal to P(A) which is finite, but what if it isn't? How do we know that it is consistent?

Comment: @ShashankKumar We make this assumption when we say $(\Omega, \Sigma, P)$ is a probability space. A probability space is a measure space $(\Omega, \Sigma)$ with a measure  $P$ with total measure $P(\Omega)=1.$ Measures obey countable additivity by definition. If it weren't true, it would not be a measure and this would not be a probability space.

Comment: Let us say, we are able to construct a sample space that is countable and assign probabilities that satisfy the non-negativity and normalization axioms, but the total probability expression is found to diverge for some partition. Let us say we are able to find such a partition and a sample space. What will it mean?

Comment: Shashank: But we cannot construct such a space since, for every $n$, $$\sum_{i=1}^nP(A_i)P(A\mid A_i)=P\left(A\cap\bigcup_{i=1}^nA_i\right)\leqslant P(A)\leqslant1$$ hence $$\sum_{i=1}^\infty P(A_i)P(A\mid A_i)=\sup_{n\geqslant1}\sum_{i=1}^nP(A_i)P(A\mid A_i)\leqslant1$$

Comment: @ShashankKumar You can certainly construct such a thing provided your 'probabilities' don't form a measure. It will mean that $P$ is not a measure cause it is not countably additive, and thus $(\Omega,\Sigma,P)$ is not a probability space. This is why there are three axioms and not two.

Comment: @Did So, you are saying that we cannot construct such a sample space if all the probability theory axioms are satisfied.

Comment: Yes. Except there is no "probability theory axioms". PT is based on ZF axioms and introduces some *definitions*, but no new axiom.

Comment: @Did By that standard the axioms of group theory, or linear orders, the real numbers, or what-have-you are not axioms either. This conflicts pretty strongly with the terminology of model theory.

Comment: @ShashankKumar I think Did's framing is helpful even if I disagree with the way he put it. The probability axioms are properties that all probability spaces have (and yes, this is simply the *definition* of a probability space). We have shown the finiteness of the sum is a consequence of the definition of a probability space, so there is no probability space you can make in which this sum diverges. If you make something that satisfies the first two axioms but not the third, and the sum diverges, it must not have satisfied the third.

Comment: @spaceisdarkgreen Yeah, I have this reasoning in my mind now.